# Class design and inheritance issue

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, smart-pointers

So in my Monopoly game I have base class `Field`, derived class `Property : public Field` and `Board` which contains array of `Field` type.

```
class Field {
protected:
    int m_position;
public:
    Field() { }
    Field(int p_position) : m_position(p_position) { }
    virtual void showProperty() const { std::cout << "Actuall output"; };
};
```

Next class is Property which derives from Field

```
class Property : public Field { 
    float m_price;
public:
    Property(int, float);
    void showProperty() const;
};
```

in property.cpp

```
Property::Property(int p_position, float p_price) : Field(p_position), m_price(p_price) { }

void Property::showProperty() const {
    std::cout <<
        "Position: " << m_position << "\n" <<
        "Price: " << std::to_string(m_price) << "\n";
}
```

Now lets see board.h

```
constexpr int BOARD_SIZE = 40;

class Board {
    std::unique_ptr<Field[]> m_board;
public:
    Board();
    Field getField(int index) { return m_board[index]; }
};
```

and its constructor

```
Board::Board() {
    m_board = std::make_unique<Field[]>(BOARD_SIZE);
    Property test(1, 100); 
    m_board[0] = test;
}
```

in main i create something like this

```
int main() {    
    Board newBoard; 
    newBoard.getField(0).showProperty();
}
```

and I expect it to call `Property::showProperty()`but it calls `Field::showProperty()`. Why isnt it using derived class function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your pointer `m_board` is a pointer to the first element of an array of `Field` objects.

That means the assignment `m_board[0] = test` will *slice* the `Property` object.

You need an array of *pointers* to `Field`. For example

```
std::array<Field*, BOARD_SIZE> m_board;
```

Of course, remember to make the pointers in the array actually point somewhere valid:

```
m_board[0] = new Property(1, 100);
```

And also of course you need to modify the `getField` function return-type to be correct.